# Is there any way to set/start an activity that will remain on top?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have an Android Xamarin application that sometimes needs to display an activity, on top of the existing one.

I do this by calling StartActivity(front_activity)
However, if while showing front_activity, the application navigates to another activity, then front_activity goes behind the new one. Is there a way to make the front_activity stick? (something like always_on_top? maybe some specific intent flags?)

Comment: So basically what you want is: If there are three activities Main,A,B when you start A from Main and then go to B from A and come back it should load Main Activity?

Comment: @G.hakim maybe I said it wrong. Say I have 3 activities: Main, A, and B. Let's say Main starts A, which shows up. Then at some point MainActivity starts B. But instead of showing B, I just need A to stay on top.

Comment: go for this link, you will get help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256821/keep-activity-always-on-top-of-stack-or-in-focus-when-rogue-apps-launch-activit

Comment: So what you want is MainAcitvity should only start activity A and never open Activity B?

Comment: @RishavSingla, actually no, I want to have one activity on top at all times, over all other activities (so it's not the app that I want on top, just one activity)

Comment: @G.hakim no, it's the opposite I want: MainActivity will start A, which needs to remain always on top, even if MainActivtity later starts B. Hope it's a bit more clear now :)

Comment: Like if i have an Activity A that is on top then no other activities should be loaded above no matter how many are started am i right?

Comment: @G.hakim yep! that's what I want to do :)

Comment: Start A inside new Task stack. Read docs for Intent.

Inside onCreate of A check Intent and open B.

Now you have new stack where B is above A, however and A and B were used before.For more help  go for this link : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: why would you need that behaviour ffs

Comment: What is B supposed to do if A is always on top of it?

Comment: I have a demo with using java ,that use WindowManager + view to do that.

Comment: @DavidWasser Exactly what I thought!

Comment: What is the purpose of Activity A? Is Activity A some UI you want show on all pages? If yes - then consider using only one Main Acitivity, with fragments inside of it (Fragment A and Fragment B below it -or what ever you need).

Comment: Activity A is meant to show a video/image, at random times. the issue is that MainActivity may also receive other events, on which it has to show different activities. I will go for the Fragments approach. Thanks @MathiasKirkegaard